# Production ready alternative to Microsoft Doloto (Javascript minifier/prefetcher)?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, minify

As you surely know Microsoft Doloto is tool which profiles you javascript code as it actually runs on the page and splits it in to two files: one file will be statically included in the footer of the page which contains stubs for all functions and loads the actual implementations (in file 2) in the background (under the assumption that only very litte javascript is needed on page load so you can defer downloading the rest).

I found Doloto not to be production ready, it meanwhile has been canceled afaik. Is there a working alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools for minifying: Google Closure Compiler and jsmin.

Comment: Thany but I am already using YUI compressor and the closure compiler can only gain a few percent above that.

Comment: These are completely different things. Doloto splits javascript into two files. One that needs to be loaded before the onload event fires and on that can be loaded after. This way you can postpone loading javascript you don't need for the initial page load to improve response times.